# random numbers and multiple srand calls

Tags: c, random, srand

I'm writing a program that will generate numerous random numbers in loops.  I'm trying to make the numbers somewhat less predictable (not only for security, but to avoid collisions on multiple threads).

I've noticed that many documents recommended calling `srand` only once in the program.  For example: [Random numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449456/random-numbers-in-c), the selected answer is "As a general rule, only call srand() once in your program".

But why?  Why would it be so bad to do something like this:

```
int THIS_THREAD_SEED;
int randomness() {
    ++THIS_THREAD_SEED;
    int i;
    for(i=0 i<1000; i++) {
        unsigned n = rand_r(&THIS_THREAD_SEED) / RAND_MAX;
        /* do something with n */
    }
    return 0;
}

int do_something() {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        randomness();
    }
}
```

As such, the seed changes once per function call, not once per program.  This way, no matter how many threads are running, no two threads will every have the same random number list... Right?

**UPDATE**
Assume I either have a unique seed for each thread, or mutex on a global SEED to prevent race conditions.

Comment: "Making numerous calls to random numbers" seems to be everyone who I've spoken to on the phone recently.

Comment: Your program most likely has a race condition on `SEED`. Before worrying about the intricacies of random number generation, it might be more important to get the basics of multi-threading right. Your idea may well be workable, but it's probably not your biggest concern.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I know how to use a mutex just fine; I didn't want to muddy up the question with extra code about threads, because this question is really about srand

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602311/thread-safe-uniform-random-number-generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's break this question into two separate ones.

1. if you worry about race conditions when **accessing** random number generator, create a mutex or other synchronization primitive to avoid this.
2. if you think about calling `srand()` several times, please, don't. the reason behind this is the random generator initialization routine which sets up the variables based on seed has worse random characteristics, gives worse performance than the random generator itself and should be not used as a substitute.

Comment: "has worse random characteristics, gives worse performance" -- exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`srand()` will *reset* the stream of numbers `rand()` will generate for you.

From the manual for srand:

> ```
>    The srand() function sets its argument as the seed for a  new  sequence
>    of  pseudo-random  integers  to be returned by rand().  These sequences
>    are repeatable by calling srand() with the same seed value.
> ```

If you need "better" random numbers then rand() provides you should look into other sources of randomness.

Also `srand()` is not used for `rand_r()`, the argument you provide (to `rand_r()`) is used instead.

And if you want to use `rand_r()` from multiple threads all threads should have a local seed, you shouldn't use a single global variable for that.

Alternatives to `rand()` can be [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html)

But if you need "real" randomness you have to look hardware support.

And to answer:

> As such, the seed changes once per function call, not once per program. This way, no matter how many threads are running, no two threads will every have the same random number list... Right?

No, doesn't work that way, you should have a thread-local SEED variable initialized to something unique for every thread. You could use `time()` for the first seed, and then use that random sequence to generate seeds for the other threads, or you read 4-8 bytes from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` if you'r using *nix.

Hope that gives some insight as this is midnight rumble, good night <3

Answer (score 0):

To avoid race conditions, you need to use a separate seed variable for each thread. This means each thread will have its own separate random number sequence.